# No model named "myapp" even though I've added it in settings.py

Tags: python, django

I'm getting the following error:

```
ImportError at /
No module named midi_app
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Django Version: 1.4.1
Exception Type: ImportError
Exception Value:    No module named midi_app
Exception Location: /Users/home/virtualenv/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py in import_module, line 35
Python Executable:  /Users/home/virtualenv/venv/bin/python
```

I have added my app "midi_app" to the `INSTALLED_APPS` section in settings.py. I'm not sure why I'm seeing this error. Could the virtualenv have anything to do with it?

Thanks.

UPDATE: I've added as many directories as I can think of and I'm still seeing this error. Please see my path below. Please assist, I'm getting really frustrated.

> '/Users/home/virtualenv/venv/lib/python27.zip',
>
> '/Users/home/virtualenv/venv/lib/python2.7',
>
> '/Users/home/virtualenv/venv/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin',
>
> '/Users/home/virtualenv/venv/lib/python2.7/plat-mac',
>
> '/Users/home/virtualenv/venv/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages',
>
> '/Users/home/virtualenv/venv/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
>
> '/Users/home/virtualenv/venv/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
>
> '/Users/home/virtualenv/venv/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
>
> '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7',
>
> '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin',
>
> '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
>
> '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac',
>
> '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages',
>
> '/Users/home/virtualenv/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
>
> '/Users/home/Desktop/Web Development/Django-1.4',
>
> '/Users/home/virtualenv/venv',
>
> '/Users/home/Desktop/Web Development/Aptana Studio 3.0',
>
> '/Users/home/virtualenv/venv/bin',
>
> '/Users/home/Desktop/Web Development',
>
> '/Users/home/virtualenv',
>
> '/Users/home/virtualenv/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PIL',
>
> '/Users/home/virtualenv/venv/lib/python27.zip',
>
> '/Users/home/virtualenv/venv/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin',
>
> '/Users/home/virtualenv/venv/lib/python2.7/plat-mac',
>
> '/Users/home/virtualenv/venv/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages',
>
> '/Users/home/virtualenv/venv/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
>
> '/Users/home/virtualenv/venv/lib/python2.7/lib-old'

Comment: show your project's directory structure. you might need to add your project name (i.e. myproject.midi_app) if your app is not under the project level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out my url was wrong.

I was specifying it as

```
url(r'^$', 'musicproject.midi_app.views.index'),
```

instead of

```
 url(r'^$', 'midi_app.views.index'),
```

Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

No the virtualenv has nothing to do with this error.
Its an `ImportError` that means that it is not able to find your app in the location you specified, recheck the path of the app and the path you provided and also the name.

Comment: i'm not sure where the discrepancy lies. The app is on my python path

Comment: I always add the full path to the top dir *and* the full path to the parent dir. There is a certain inconsistency in how various apps are imported/referenced and this makes that problem go away.

Comment: @PeterRowell, thanks for your response. I've added my path; perhaps, that might provide more clues to my issue

Comment: should my project be in virtualenv? in the src folder?

Answer (score 0):

One other thing to note, you have to have a:

```
__init__.py
```

file (empty is fine, just use "touch **init**.py") in every directory leading to your app that is in the python path.

So if you have a structure like this:

```
my_project/
    manage.py
    __init__.py
    urls.py
    settings.py
    apps/
        __init__.py <---- this has to be here
        midi_app/
            __init__.py <--- this also has to be here
            models.py
            admin.py
            views.py
            urls.py
```

It's simple thing to overlook.

Comment: thanks @powellc but that's not my problem. I have the init.py files. I'm using aptana studio ide and that assists with that issue.